# Can the magic ticket be used more than once?

Tags: plot-explanation, last-action-hero

In the 1993 movie *Last Action Hero*, can the magic ticket be used more than one time? Like for multiple movies/show? I think that it must not be, as the ticket was torn into two at the start of the movie, and as in the real world ordinary tickets cannot be used more than once.

In one of the scenes, Nick (the projectionist) expresses excitement and speaks about the movies he would like to get into.

Comment: Are you trying to get a sequel made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the ticket is used on multiple movies in the movie.  Benedict used the ticket to grab the Ripper from *Slater III*.  Also, Death from *The Seventh Seal* comes out of his movie towards the end of the film.

Comment: But that is while the movie Slater IV is going on. While Slater IV is going on, anything that is done by the characters of Slater IV is counted as a single movie.

Comment: That would be incorrect.  The events in the movie are actually over a couple of days at least in the real world.  Also, at the end of the movie they **start up a reel of the movie**, so not all of the events happen during one showing of the movie.